# Generating 3 Random Numbers Within a Range and sum 3 numbers = this range

Tags: php, random, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make 5 random numbers with sum of 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289136/how-to-make-5-random-numbers-with-sum-of-100)

i am new with php . Can i ask how to make 3 random number with range an sum of 3 numbers  = max value of this range.

Example : i have range 0->900; 3 random number is 213 437 250

Answer (score 3):

Pick two random numbers between 0 and 900 inclusive. Add 0 and 900 to the list. Sort them. Your numbers are the 3 differences between successive numbers.

For example, say you pick 503 and 117. Your sorted list is 0, 117, 503, 900. So your differences are:

117 - 0 = 117
503 - 117 = 386
900 - 503 = 397

So your three numbers are 117, 386, and 397.

Since you only need three numbers, you can simplify the process: Generate two random numbers between 0 and 900 (inclusive). Call the larger A and the smaller B. Your numbers are `B`, `A - B` and `900 - A`.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064754/721269).